# How to process the JSON request sent from ASP.NET WEB API to AWS Lambda using node.js

Tags: node.js, asp.net-web-api, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to process the request sent from ASP.NET WEB API to AWS API and process it with Lambda function :

this is the way i am calling the REST API deployed in AWS:

```
// Serialize our concrete class into a JSON String
var stringPayload = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload));
// Wrap our JSON inside a StringContent which then can be used by the HttpClient class
var httpContent = new StringContent(stringPayload,Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient()) {
    // Do the actual request and await the response
    var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://hosteddress-2.amazonaws.com/prod/SlashcmdIntegeration", httpContent);
    // If the response contains content we want to read it!
    if (httpResponse.Content != null) {
        var responseContent = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        // From here on you could deserialize the ResponseContent back again to a concrete C# type using Json.Net
    }
}
```

this is code in aws lambda to process it:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var qs = require('querystring');
var https=require('https');
var token;
exports.handler = function (event, context) {
    processEvent(event, context);  
};

var processEvent = function(event, context) {
    var body = event.body;
    var params = qs.parse(body);
    var commandText = params.CommandText;
    var arr = commandText.split(" "); 
    var op1 = arr[0];
    var op2 = arr[1];
    var op = arr[2]; 
    var result;
    switch(op) {
        case "+":
            result = Number(op1) + Number(op2);
            break;
        case "-":
            result = Number(op1) - Number(op2);
            break;
        case "*":
            result = Number(op1) * Number(op2);
            break;
        case "/":
            result = Number(op2)===0 ? NaN : Number(op1) / Number(op2);
            break;
        default:
            result = "Invalid op";
    }
    console.log('data sent');
    context.succeed(result);
};
```

i tried to debug it  **`var body = event.body;`** is undefined however I have set it in the integration request and eventually landing to  below error message:

> { "errorMessage": "Process exited before completing request" }

Any idea on this please?

Thanks

Comment: didn't get this `var body = event.body; it not undefined`, do you get the body in your request?

Comment: @AJS . That's the issue I think, event.body is undefined however it should get the body as I have properly set in the integration request of AWS API.

Comment: the error means the api request failed as it didnt send any response.

Answer (score 0):

From what i can understand from above code

> { "errorMessage": "Process exited before completing request" }

This error occurs when your process is unable to send a response as some error occurred before it could do so.I would suggest you check the body before starting to parse it like this

```js
var processEvent = function(event, context) {
  var body = event.body;
  var result;
  if (body) {

    var params = qs.parse(body);
    var commandText = params.CommandText;
    var arr = commandText.split(" ");
    var op1 = arr[0];
    var op2 = arr[1];
    var op = arr[2];

    switch (op) {
      case "+":
        result = Number(op1) + Number(op2);
        break;
      case "-":
        result = Number(op1) - Number(op2);
        break;
      case "*":
        result = Number(op1) * Number(op2);
        break;
      case "/":
        result = Number(op2) === 0 ? NaN : Number(op1) / Number(op2);
        break;
      default:
        result = "Invalid op";
    }
  }

  console.log('data sent');
  context.succeed(result);
};
```

As for what is causing the error i am not quite sure as i have not used lambda, this is purely from nodejs point of view.

Comment: i will update the answer if i find any particular useful information that could help related to  lamda

Comment: in integration request of API i have given the body mapping template as: {"body" : $input.json('$') } ,event is not accepting it in the node.js handler.i have just tried it with direct call like event.[parameter name] is working :)

Comment: i found this is a nice and clean implementation may be try this.https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/how-to-turn-node-js-projects-into-aws-lambda-microservices-easily-with-claudiajs/

Comment: this feels much more practical approach as it could allow you to have multiple endpoints instead of just one function and also does a lot of work for you. I haven't used lamda so i may be wrong, just speaking of experience with node :)

Answer (score 0):

Calling parameter directly from event is working:

```
 var processEvent = function(event, context) {
      var body = event.CommandText;/*parameter name*/
      var result;
      if (body) {


        var arr = body.split(" ");
        var op1 = arr[0];
        var op2 = arr[1];
        var op = arr[2];

        switch (op) {
          case "+":
            result = Number(op1) + Number(op2);
            break;
          case "-":
            result = Number(op1) - Number(op2);
            break;
          case "*":
            result = Number(op1) * Number(op2);
            break;
          case "/":
            result = Number(op2) === 0 ? NaN : Number(op1) / Number(op2);
            break;
          default:
            result = "Invalid op";
        }
      }

      console.log('data sent');
      context.succeed(result);
    };
```

just wondering about the use of body mapping template.